# How to re-initialize page objects in protractor before each scenario?

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, pageobjects

I am using protractor with cucumber and trypescript. I have all my page objects defined as classes. In the steps definition, I initialize every page object needed and use that for various assertions or actions. The setup works fine when running one scenario. However, if I want to run more scenarios, I need to find a way to re-initialize the page objects for each scenario, otherwise protractor will use previously-initialized objects with elements that were acquired for the first browser instance and I will get an error.

Any ideas on how to do that? I have tried to look after project examples on github but couldn't find anything that addresses my problem.

This is a small example from my setup:

loginpage.po.ts:

```
export class LoginPage{
    ...     
    async login(username:string,password:string){
        await this.enteremail(username);
        await this.clickNext();
        await this.enterPass(password);
        await this.clickSignIn();
   ...
}
    }
```

common.steps.ts:

```
import { LoginPage} from '../pageobjects/loginPage.po';
...
var loginPage: LoginPage= new LoginPage();

Given('I have the URL ', async () => {
    await browser.get(config.baseUrl);
    await expect(loginPage.isAtSignIn()).to.eventually.be.true;
});

 Given ('I login', async () => {
     await loginPage.login(config.params.username, config.params.password);
 });
```

Comment: Your approach looks correct. Please show the error you got.

Comment: When running two scenarios, I am getting the following error for the second scenario: "NoSuchSessionError: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used." If I move the initialization of the LoginPage inside the "Given" function, both scenarios pass. However, was wondering if there is a more elengant way to do this, instead of initializing page objects in step definitions (because this approach might cause problems when I want to reuse some of the steps in other scanrios)

Comment: Check your code to see you close the browser session in after hook or last step of the first scenario. like call `browser.quite()`.  Or set `restartBrowser` in protractor conf.js

Comment: Yes, I have this in the hooks.ts and it is executed as I can see from the logs:  After(async () => {
      await browser.quit();
  });

Comment: If close browser after each scenario is not a mandatory option, remove it from after hook.

Comment: I have to close the browser as I have different logins and I need to login each time

Comment: If so, you can try restartBrowserBetweenTests: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L554

Comment: The same thing happens when using restartBrowserBetweenTests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function in your spec file

```
initializePageObjects() {
var loginPage: LoginPage= new LoginPage();
}
```

Now add this function in your `beforeEach()` so that you class gets initialized for every `it()`.

```
beforeEach(){
await initializePageObjects();
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: It works like that. However, I've decided to initialize and return page objects from the methods, so I avoid initializing all page object in the beginning. I will mark the response as correct, as the proposed solution works.